# Facial recognition with props in PHP lagging when changing props

Tags: javascript, ajax, camera, getusermedia

I found a [facial recognition library](https://github.com/neave/face-detection) with props but wanted for it to be able to change props that you use instead of only one prop.

I put the function of `face.html` inside a `onclick` function where you send the `src` and it will make the camera with props for you. It works however it keeps getting laggy as you choose one prop from another. The script uses the `getUserMedia` API.

I tried deleting content of `div` and recreating the camera however it doesn't work.

Comment: What are "props" in this context? What does "it doesn't work" mean in detail? Can we see your code?

Comment: The link you provide is not PHP but js?

Comment: Its not actually php im trying to integrate it into php the problem is it gets slower every time i use the onclick function to call a different prop